# How to assign and measure row height?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to measure row heights to ensure that a printed sheet will fit on a certain number of pages.

When I read row heights from Excel using VBA, they differ from the row height I see in Excel when I right-click a row to view height.

For example, I have three rows at the top of a sheet. In VBA, I set the height of each row:

1. Row 1: 30 (contains vCompanyNameCell)
2. Row 2: 21 (contains vReportNameCell)
3. Row 3: 31 (contains vReportDateCell)

```vb
Public Sub setTitleAreaCellsToDefaultHeight()
    vCompanyNameCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = cHTitleCompanyLine   '30
    vReportNameCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = cHTitleReportLine     '21
    vReportDateCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = cHTitleDateLine       '31
    Stop 
End Sub
```

When the code breaks on `Stop` above, I go to the sheet and view the height of the first row, and it is correct at 30.
[image]

After these heights are set, I have VBA code that reads the height of each cell:

```vb
Public Sub getCurrentHeights()
    vHCurrCompanyCell = vCompanyNameCell.EntireRow.height
    vHCurrReportCell = vReportNameCell.EntireRow.height
    vHCurrCompanyCell = vReportDateCell.EntireRow.height    
    Stop    
End Sub
```

When I `Stop` in the code above, then hover over the values in the first line in the VBA editor, I see this:

[image]

[image]

VBA is saying the height is 30, which is what I set it to, but somehow the result is off by 0.75. So is the height of the row 30 or 30.75?

Also how is the left side of the equation not the same as the right side?
I thought it had to do with `.RowHeight.Height` property being a double, but if I round the right side of the equation to 0 decimals, I still get crazy results:

[image]

[image]

Even though I rounded the double to 0 decimals, it's still saying the height of the cell is 30.75 instead of 30.

Similar problem here https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-formula-for-row-height-gives-incorrect-amount.235649/, but their solution was to hard code the heights and I can't do that, I need to read heights as they are.

So 2 questions:

1. Is the height 30 or 30.75
2. If it's 30 as I expect, how can I get VBA to read that.

Here is a reproducible example.
On my computer, the value of `outputHeight3` turns out to be 30.75 instead of 31.
Is the height on the worksheet 30.75 or 31?

```vb
Public Sub test()
    
    Stop
    
    Dim companyNameHeight As Integer
    Dim reportNameHeight As Integer
    Dim reportDateHeight As Integer
    
    Dim height As Double
    Dim rounded As Double
    
    Dim outputHeight1 As Double
    Dim outputHeight2 As Double
    Dim outputHeight3 As Double
    
    Dim companyNameCell As Range
    Dim reportNameCell As Range
    Dim reportDateCell As Range
    
    companyNameHeight = 30
    reportNameHeight = 21
    reportDateHeight = 31
    
    'set height of the rows
    Set companyNameCell = Worksheets("OUTPUT - BS").Range("OUTPUT_BS_COMPANY_NAME")
    companyNameCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = companyNameHeight
    Set reportNameCell = Worksheets("OUTPUT - BS").Range("OUTPUT_BS_REPORT_NAME")
    reportNameCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = reportNameHeight
    Set reportDateCell = Worksheets("OUTPUT - BS").Range("OUTPUT_BS_REPORT_DATE")
    reportDateCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = reportDateHeight
    
    Stop
    
    'read height of the rows
    outputHeight1 = vCompanyNameCell.EntireRow.height
    outputHeight2 = reportNameCell.EntireRow.height
    outputHeight3 = reportDateCell.EntireRow.height
    
    Stop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Read the height but do not round it. The height increases by one step... I think it depends on the default font.

Comment: *how is the left side of the equation not the same as the right side* - in vba an equals sign is used for both equality comparisons and as an assignment operator. `x = myrange.Entire.RowHeight` is an assignment. LH and RH sides do not need to be equal, rather the left hand side will be assigned the value of the right-hand side (i.e, "take what's here and put it there").

Comment: I think you are limited in the heights you can set by reality (pixels, points, perhaps font-size plays a role as noted in a previous comment). You should probably choose 30.75 or 31.5 instead of 31. Or set it to 31 and take the best approximation Excel gives you (i.e., if it becomes 30.75 when you read it back the so be it - go with 30.75).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguish between `RowHeight` and `Height` of a Range.
You can set the `RowHeight` to any number you want (except there is a maximum value of 409), but Excel will round it to the nearest quarter.

The `Height` is a read-only value and will be calculated depending on the `RowHeight`, but the result must be an integer value of *Pixels*: Change the Row height in Excel using the mouse: You will see that you can increase/decrease the height only by steps of 1 Pixel.

[image]

The measurement of RowHeight (and Height) is in *Points*, and there are usually 72 Point per Inch. The number of *Pixels* per Inch is defined by the device (your monitor). The most common value is 96 Pixel per Inch, therefore the formula would be

```
pixels = height * 96 / 72
height = pixels * 72 / 96
```

That means 14 pixels would result in 14 * 72 / 96 = 10.5
The next possible bigger height would be 15 pixels = 15 * 72 / 96 = 11.25
There can't be a `Height` value in between 10.5 and 11.25

If you are interested:
Use [`Application.InchesToPoints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inchestopoints) to get the number of of points per Inch
Use [`Workbook.WebOptions.PixelsPerInch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.weboptions.pixelsperinch) to get the number of pixels per Inch.

Comment: It's really *fun* reading your instructive but simple explanations +:) @FunThomas

Answer (score 0):

#!$!@#!@#!@

I was trying to get height with

```
Cell.EntireRow.Height
```

instead of

```
Cell.EntireRow.RowHeight
```

using .RowHeight is giving me the values I expected. pfft.